# Tomcat - A child container failed during start - After converting maven to gradle

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, gradle

I converted my project from `maven` to `gradle`.
After converting while startup my tomcat server I am getting the following error log.

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Tabserve-Superadmin]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Tabserve-Superadmin]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.(WsServerContainer.java:147)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5573)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Nov 01, 2016 2:37:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:756)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     ... 6 more
>
> Nov 01, 2016 2:37:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>   SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8005]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:756)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>     ... 11 more

These are my dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'MyApp'
    version = '0.0.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'lib')
    compile project(':Model_v102')

    compile("org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-tx:3.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:3.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-web:3.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jms:3.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("dom4j:dom4j:1.1")
    compile("cglib:cglib:2.1_3")
    compile("com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.1")
    compile("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.4")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2")
    compile("commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2.2")
    compile('commons-codec:commons-codec:1.7')
    compile("org.jasypt:jasypt:1.7.1")
    compile("net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.5.2")
    compile("commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6")
    compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1")
    compile("javassist:javassist:3.12.0.GA")
    compile("com.sun.faces:jsf-api:2.1.7")
    compile("com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:2.1.7")
    compile("javax:javaee-api:6.0")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.3.0.Final")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.5.1-Final")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.5.1-Final")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.15")
    compile("org.primefaces:primefaces:3.5")
    compile("joda-time:joda-time:2.1")
    compile("c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.1")
    //compile("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
    compile("com.caucho:resin-hessian:4.0.1")
    compile("org.apache.poi:poi:3.7")
    compile("com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.0.6")
    compile("net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.1.0")
    compile("org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.1.1")
    compile("log4j:log4j:1.2.15")
    //providedCompile("org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:7.0.29")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String
```

This method has been added in Servlet 3.1. Are you sure you are deploying to the correct Tomcat version?

Answer (score 1):

As @chkal said it looks like a different version of `servlet-api` is on the classpath. Try comparing the following from command line

`mvn dependency:tree` (from the old maven build)

`gradle dependencies` (from the gradle build)

I'm guessing the `servlet-api` version is different in maven vs gradle build. Maven will use a "nearest definition wins" strategy to resolve multiple versions of an artifact whereas gradle will use the latest version. Note that you can [customise the way that gradle resolves dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:finetuning_the_dependency_resolution_process).